# FFmpeg - Concat Videos with different rotations

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rotation, concatenation

I want to concat two Videos that have different Rotations 90 and 270.

Here is the command that I used:

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4`

In list.txt are the paths to both videos.

What I found out is that the Output Video gets the Rotation of the Video that is listed first in list.txt. So when the Video with Rotation 90 is first, the output video gets the Rotation 90. In the Output Video the second Video will be upside down.

I tried the Flag `-noautorotate`, but nothing changed.

How do I keep the rotation of all Videos, so that the rotation of the first isnt forced onto the others?

Comment: Not possible without re-encoding.

Comment: As @Gyan said, not possible. You have to use the -complex_filter option, unfortunately.